# Python: sum function with for loop: different results

Tags: python, for-loop, sum

Here is the code:

```
d = {1 : 1, 2 : 2, 3 : 2}
s, s1 = 0, 0
for e in d:
    s += sum(x for x in range(d[e]))
s1 = sum(sum(y for y in range(d[e])) for e in d)
print(f"s: {s}, s1: {s1}")
```

**Why `s == 2, but s1 == 3`?**

I expect `s == s1 == 2`.

It looks that interpreter knows an internal variable `e` from the for-loop prior the first run of the `sum()` function .

Comment: Can't reproduce?

Comment: As per @Timus, this code works as expected for me. You must have some code before this that is affecting the results, or you've changed the code in order to post it here and in doing so have removed your problem.

Comment: I used a Python interpreter on this [site](https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/lists/problems/num_equal_pairs/). Yes, you are right: the code works as expected. I have tested it on my local machine. Thank you, @Kemp